# Can the verb 'break' be used for 'wall'

Tags: verbs

Can the verb **break** be used for **wall**?

As in the following sentence:

> Why did she break the garden wall?

Comment: It would help to know **why** you think this might be problematic

Answer (score 2):

Certainly.  "Break" can be used for both "cause to stop working" and "smash into pieces".

"Break the wall" is quite correct.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, That works. You can use break, damage, destroy (although that implies quite a bit more damage than just break / damage )